# Redirecting To External URL

Tags: google-app-maker

I want a redirect to be triggered on a certain action but am running into issues with same origin policies.

Has anyone had any luck redirecting to external URLs (I can't use `app.showPage`)?

I've tried `window.location.href` but it's blocked because the iframe that the app is loaded into does not allow cross-origin requests.

At best I've gotten `window.open` to work but because of the cross-origin policy it opens in a new page even if the `windowName` parameter is set to `window.name`.

Comment: What is your redirect triggered from? Is it a link or a script action, or something else? If it's a link you can put your URL into the link href and then you can designate how it opens in the editor by choosing '_self', '_blank', or something else. On a note, app.showPage is part of App Maker API, therefore it would not work on external URLs. Your best option would be to insert a link widget and set the URL and target.

Comment: It is a script and triggered by some logic instead of a user clicking on one of those link widgets.  I believe the link widget just creates an absolute link instead of triggering some code.